# Custom listener is not registered

Tags: java, android, listener

I have a `MyService` class which implements custom `CallReceiver.Listener` . The problem is listener registration called in `MyService` is not working. `mListener` in `CallReceiver` is always null. It proves that listener was not registerd, but I have no idea why is that.

MyService class (an extract):

```
public class MyService extends Service implements CallReceiver.Listener {

CallReceiver mCallReceiver;

   public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    serviceStart();
    return startId;
   }

    // starting service
    public void serviceStart()  {

    mCallReceiver = new CallReceiver();

    // registering listener for CallReceiver
    mCallReceiver.registerListener(this);
   }


    public void onPhoneStateChange(boolean state) {
     if (state) {
        Log.v("onPhoneStateChange", "service destroyed");
        serviceDestroy();
    } else {
        // serviceStart();
    }
  }

}
```

CallReceiver class:

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver   {

private boolean isRinging = false;
private Listener mListener = null;

// interface declaration
 public interface Listener {
        public void onPhoneStateChange(boolean state);
    }

// listener registration
 public void registerListener (Listener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        if(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state))  {
            // do something while ringing
                Log.v("phone", "ringing");
                isRinging = true;
        }


        else if(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(state))    {
            //do something when the call ends
            Log.v("phone", "idle");
            isRinging = false;
        }


        if(mListener != null)   {
            // onPhoneStateChange is not called because mListener is null
            mListener.onPhoneStateChange(isRinging);
        }

  }

}
```

Comment: You never register the Receiver, that's a likely issue. Also, if this Receiver is part of the Manifest, it is very likely the system will make a separate instance not tied to your service, which leaves `mListener` null.

Comment: CallReceiver is now statically registered in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: I'd say it should *not* be in the manifest at all. Instead, your service should make an IntentFilter then register it dynamically. I'll post a code sample soon. I have no idea what `Intent` Actions your receiver needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register your receiver dynamically.

```
// registering listener for CallReceiver
   mCallReceiver.registerListener(this);
   IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("your.Intent");
   registerReceiver (mCallReceiver, filter);
```

Also, in your services onDestroy(), don't forget to unregister it.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy ()
{
    try {
    unregisterReceiver (broadcastReceiver);
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e){}
    catch (NullPointerException ne){}
    super.onDestroy();
}
```